# How to take wakelock from shell command on android

Tags: android, command, sh, wakelock

Trying to improve my terminal application on Android.

And need to take Wakelock there.

So, how to take Wakelock from shell command on Android.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

shell command to acquire a wake lock

```
  echo lock_me > /sys/power/wake_lock
```

shell command to release the same wake_lock

```
  echo lock_me > /sys/power/wake_unlock
```